# CakePHP allow searching by field using API?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create an API using CakePHP that allows searching. For example:

```
http://localhost:8765/users/index/?username=admin
```

Which should return users with usernames equal to 'admin':

```
users: [
   {
      id: 3,
      username: "admin",
      image: "",
      firstName: "Jeremy",
      lastName: "Quick",
      userTypeId: 1,
      email: "jrquick@test.com",
      groupId: 2
   }
]
```

So far, I have been able to accomplish this with a custom get() in the AppController which checks the $_GET and $_POST array for fields on the model. But the function is getting more and more complicated and verging on hackiness as I add more functionality (range search, collection search, and child table filtering). Is there a better, more CakePHP friendly way of accomplishing this? Whether through pure cakephp or a plugin?

Comment: Side note, never access superglobals directly when using CakePHP, this will just bring you in trouble, especially when working with controller tests! Use the provided wrappers on [**the request object**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters) instead.

Comment: Just use the Friends of Cake Search plugin. It's well written, small, easy to use and you can implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get with it. It makes it really easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an answer that seems to work exactly how I am wanting, so here is my current get command. It does allow searching by fields, join tables, greater/less than, in array, and like.

If anyone has recommendations to improve I will update my answer.

```
public function get() {
    $response = new Response();

    $model = $this->loadModel();

    $fields = $this->getFields();
    $joins = $this->getJoins();
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $params = $this->getParams();
    $limit = $this->getLimit();
    $offset = $this->getOffset();

    $query = $model->find('all', ['fields' => $fields]);
    if (!is_null($joins)) {
        $query->contain($joins);
    }
    if (sizeof($params['equals']) > 0) {
        foreach ($params['equals'] as $equalsKey=>$equalsValue) {
            $query->andWhere([$equalsKey => $equalsValue]);
        }
    }
    if (sizeof($params['or']) > 0) {
        foreach ($params['or'] as $orKey=>$orValue) {
            $query->orWhere([$orKey => $orValue]);
        }
    }
    if (!is_null($order)) {
        $query->order([$order]);
    }
    if (!is_null($limit)) {
        $query->limit($limit);
        if (!is_null($offset)) {
            $query->offset($offset);
        }
    }
    $response->addMessage($model->table(), $query->toArray());

    $response->respond($this);
}

private function getFields() {
    $fields = [];
    if (array_key_exists('fields', $_GET)) {
        $fields = explode(',', $_GET['fields']);
    }

    return $fields;
}

private function getLimit() {
    $limit = null;
    if (array_key_exists('limit', $_GET)) {
        $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    }

    return $limit;
}

private function getJoins() {
    $joins = null;
    if (array_key_exists('joins', $_GET)) {
        $joins = explode(',', $_GET['joins']);
    }

    return $joins;
}

private function getOffset() {
    $offset = null;
    if (array_key_exists('offset', $_GET)) {
        $offset = $_GET['limit'];
    }

    return $offset;
}

private function getOrder() {
    $results = [];

    if (array_key_exists('order', $_GET)) {
        $orders = explode(',', $_GET['order']);

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $sign = substr($order, 0, 1);
            $direction = 'ASC';
            if (in_array($sign, ['+', '-'])) {
                if ($sign === '-') {
                    $direction = 'DESC';
                }

                $order = substr($order, 1);
            }

            $result = $order;
            if (strpos($result, '.') === false) {
                $result = $this->loadModel()->alias() . '.' . $order;
            }
            $result = $result . ' ' . $direction;

            $results[] = $result;
        }
    }

    return (sizeof($results) == 0) ? null : implode(',', $results);
}

private function getParams() {
    $params = [
        'equals' => [],
        'or'     => []
    ];

    $parentModel = $this->loadModel();

    $array = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
    foreach ($array as $field=>$value) {
        $comparisonType = 'equals';
        $operator = substr($field, strlen($field) - 1);
        if (in_array($operator, ['!', '>', '<'])) {
            $field = substr($field, 0, strlen($field) - 1);
            $operator .= '=';
        } else if (in_array($operator, ['|'])) {
            $field = substr($field, 0, strlen($field) - 1);
            $comparisonType = 'or';
            $operator = '=';
        } else if (in_array($operator, ['%'])) {
            $field = substr($field, 0, strlen($field) - 1);
            $operator = 'LIKE';
            $value = '%'.$value.'%';
        } else {
            $operator = '=';
        }

        if ($value == 'null') {
            $operator = (strpos($operator, '!') === false) ? 'IS' : 'IS NOT';
            $value = null;
        }

        $field = str_replace('_', '.', $field);
        if (strpos($field, '.') === false) {
            $alias = $parentModel->alias();
        } else {
            $fieldExplosion = explode('.', $field);
            $alias = $fieldExplosion[0];
            $field = $fieldExplosion[1];
        }

        $model = null;
        if ($parentModel->alias() !== $alias) {
            $association = $parentModel->associations()->get($alias);
            if (!is_null($association)) {
                $model = $this->loadModel($association->className());
            }
        } else {
            $model = $parentModel;
        }

        if (!is_null($model)) {
            if ($model->hasField(rtrim($field, 's')) && !$model->hasField($field)) {
                $field = rtrim($field, 's');
                $value = '(' . $value . ')';
                $operator = ' IN';
            }

            if ($model->hasField($field)) {
                $params[$comparisonType][$alias.'.'.$field . ' ' . $operator] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the Cakephp Search plugin. It has good documentation and uses a PRG method similar to what you are currently using. It will function just fine through an API.  Here's a link to that plugin: [github.com/FriendsOfCake/search](http://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to create API, You should create a [MiddleWare](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html) at first, which will filter tokens, keys etc. to make Your API more protected.
Also, You should use [Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html) and [RESTful Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes), which will be very helpful.

To create plugin:
`bin/cake bake plugin Api`

Create Model:
`bin/cake bake model Users`

For example, You want to have UsersController in Api plugin:

```
<?php  
namespace Api\Controller;

/* This controller will be extending like parent */
use Api\Controller\AppController;
use Api\Model\Table\UsersTable;
/**
* Class UsersController
* @package Api\Controller
* @property UsersTable $Users
* 
*/
class UsersController extends AppController{
   public function initialize(){
       parent::initialize();
       $this->loadModel('Api.Users');
   }

   public function getUser($field ='username', $username = false){
       return $this->_jsonResponse(
           [
             'users' => $this->Users->findBy{ucfirst($field)}($username)
           ];
       )
   }

   public function _jsonResponse($data, $code = 200){
       $this->response->type('json');
       $this->response->statusCode($code);
       $this->response->body(
           json_encode((array)$data)
       );
       return $this->response;
   }       

}
```

Route will be descripbed in `plugins/config/routes.php`. You need to create Route Map for API in `/api` path:

```
function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources('Users', [
        'map' => [
            'get-user' => [
                'action' => 'getUser',
                'method' => 'GET' /* Can be also as array ['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'] */
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
}
```

If You have frequent calls, You should use [Cache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html) that calls and save them for some amount of time. For example - `10 minutes`. Cache can be configured in `config/app.php`. You should create separate Cache prefix and use it in this way:

```
<?php
use Cake\Cache\Cache;

$data = [];

Cache::write('some_key', $data, 'prefix') 
dump(Cache::read('some_key', 'prefix'));
```

It's just examples. If You will face some problems - just tell in comments :)

Also, use [Migrations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html) and [Seeds](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#seed-seeding-your-database) instead dumping sql files

If You want to filter data from Middleware - You should have [Event](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/namespace-Cake.Event.html) as argument, that will contain request data (`$_POST`) and request query(`$_GET`) variables that You will be able to easily handle with.
From controllers You need to use `$this->request->data` to get `POST` data array or `$this->request->query` to get `GET` data array.

Comment: Also, `_jsonResponse()` method should be located in `src/Controller/AppController.php` (Main Controller) to have access from anywhere and have a `protected` access modificator.

Comment: Route for this call will be :
`http://example.com/{plugin_path}/{controller}/{method}` -
`http://example.com/api/users/get-user/firstName/Jeremy`

Comment: Note, that it will return You `application/json` as `Content-Type`. With this, You don't need to deal with `JSON.parse(obj)`, because it will be automatically transformed into `object` according to content type